# World with mostly whites people?

Tags: behaviour

Say most of the black color people become extinct and majority of the people on earth are white color .

Do the white people think black people appear more beautiful and think of become   becoming black people like applying blacking cream similar to fairness cream or Photoshop their photo to more dark tone .

I know this is opinion based . But I want to know the science behind people wanting a particular skin color.

I don't know about other countries , but here in India people think white is clean and black / dark color with dirtiness  .

Comment: This sound more like a sociological question, and has no worldbuilding at all. And it is also opinion based: some like pale appearances, some other fall for deep tanned people... de gustibus non disputandum est

Comment: Depending on your culture, "white" people (aka Europoids) may already be quite dark. For example, in continental Europe we consider the Europoid race to include everybody from Iceland in the north and west to Morocco, Algeria and Egypt in the south, to Afghanistan and northern India in the east. The skin tone of a Swede is very light, and the skin tone of a Touareg is pretty dark, but both are Europoid. So you must explain what a "white person" actually *is* in your culture. Are Persians white? Are Arabs white? Indians? All Indians, including for example Kerala, or only some of them?

Comment: And BTW, you do know that many white people like to sunbathe in order to make their skin become darker in color? In many places there are businesses which offer such darkening using ultraviolet light; see [indoor tanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_tanning).

Comment: I don't know how to put it without shocking you, but...there is no 'black people gene'. Ok? We're all the same DNA everywhere, really. Our differentiations come from generational adaption to the environment. Even if you magically extinguished all black people NOW, every arian going to live in Africa, after due time, will turn out a nice permanent tan and develop other characteristics to make best of the hot climate. have a nice day!

Comment: As others have said there is no predicting fashion trends.  For many centuries middle and upper class Europeans, especially woman, tried to look as pale as possible so they wouldn't be confused with peasants who worked outdoors.  In recent centuries when middle class people usually work indoors, they desire to be tanned to look like people with enough leisure time for outdoor sports.  As someone with pale skin who has suffered from bad sunburns, I prefer a fashion for people to avoid sunlight and skin cancer as much as possible.
 andogical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is very strongly related to culture and perception of other cultures, but mostly its random.

There are lots of clichés like black men prefer white women, white men prefer asian women, etc.. Those are stereotypes but they could show tendencies.
Those tendencies are basically random as there is no real, objective reason for that.

Some native central americans thought the whites that arrived were gods. As in their mythology gods often were pale skinned - then actually seeing pale skinned people blew their minds.

Also: Exotic is exciting. There is always a special place for exotic things in people's minds. Same goes for exotic partners.

#### The evolutionary perspective

What is the benefit of preferring other skin colours / other melanin amounts? While you're in your area you've been genetically adapted to for hundreds of generations?
None, your skin colour is most likely better for this enviroment.

**BUT** people from vastly different enviroments have a significant amount of other minor adaptions. So they bring new stuff to the gene pool. That is a benefit for the entirety of the population.

All you can say for sure is that the more exotic varieties will get some special attention - which can be dampened or enhanced by cultural influence.

Examples:

- Most traditionalist places have the general public being rather uninterested in other cultures and people. In Japan there is a strong preference of other japanese people. It is a very conservative place and they have one of the lowest refugee numbers of all first world countries. Far below even the US.
- In arabic countries you will not see that many couples with black and non-black people. The arabic word for "black man" literally means or comes from the word "slave". A strong preference for black people is pretty unlikely in that area.

### Conclusion

There is no way of predicting the development of random preferences in general.